# Comparison of Regex flavours

Tags: java, javascript, regex, perl, sed

I wonder if there is a comparison between the features of various regex metacharacters in various implementations.

The sort of thing I am looking for is a table like

```
Language       Perl    sed
grouping       ( )     \( \)
```

Languages I am interested in are Perl, Sed Java  Javascript

Answer (score 14):

There's a comprehensive comparison page here: [Regular Expression Flavor Comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Some languages implement a particular style, so look up your language on that page and determine which column to look at. For example, JavaScript will be under ECMA. For sed it depends on whether you're using UNIX or Linux (from the page):

> The sed UNIX tool uses POSIX BRE.
>   Linux usually ships with the GNU
>   implementation, which use "GNU BRE".

Comment: You may find very useful a tool called "regex buddy", it allows to convert regular expressions from one language to another.

Answer (score 10):

A script called [`txt2regex`](http://aurelio.net/soft/txt2regex/) allows you to build a regex and shows you the syntax for various flavors.

[image: txt2regex]